# Show image when pressing submit button in form codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Basically my problems is same with this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?175212-Show-image-when-pressing-submit-button-in-form) i already following the suggestion.. but it doesn't works.
So.. i have a table where displaying name and origin who i get from database. And later can be input additional information.
when user click Add, there will be modal form. After user input the data and click submit i want to display an image (something like successfully add) but the image must be invisible until the submit is pressed.

The view

```js
<script language="javascript">
    function showImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImg_<?php echo $i; ?>');
    image.style.display = '';
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php  
   if(isset($results)>0){$i=1; foreach($results as $row)  {  
   ?>  
  <tr>  
   <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
   <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->origin; ?></td>
   <td><img name="myImg" id="myImg_<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo base_url('images/ok.png'); ?>" width="20" height="20" style="display:none;" /></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="open-InputDataDialog btn btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $row->name;?>" data-origin-id="<?php echo $row->origin ;?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InputDataDialog">Add </button></td>
 </tr>  
<?php $i++;}}?>
```

The modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="inputNilaiDialog" role="dialog" >
```

...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'people/save'?>" onSubmit="return showImage();">

  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" readonly />
      </div>                  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Telp" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telp</label>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Telp" name="Telp" readonly />
      </div>                  
    </div>  

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>

  </form>
  ..
```

**UPDATE :**
What i want to achieve is when user click add button and input data into form as modal box, the image (checklist icon) will be appear like below.

[image]

Comment: this is very unclear what you want to achieve..."And later can be input additional information. when user click Add, there will be modal form."

Comment: The tutorial link you following is for a single `img` element, are you trying to show multiple images on a single modal pop up?

Comment: @Vickel Sorry if my explanation is not clear. What i want to achieve is when user click submit button the image will be appear in column "status". I will update the question, so you will be understand (i hope)

Comment: @HastaDhana please see my updates, i hope you will understand it

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-rowid` on each button to provide a unique row `ID` value :

```
<td>
    <button type="button" data-rowid="<?php echo $i; ?>" 
     class="open-InputDataDialog btn btn-default" 
     data-id="<?php echo $row->name;?>" 
     data-origin-id="<?php echo $row->origin ;?>" 
     data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#InputDataDialog">Add </button>
</td>
```

add an input to the modal form   :

```
<input type="hidden" id="rowid" name="rowid" value="" />
```

On `Add` button click, set `rowid` on the form so that it has the same `rowid` value as the `Add` button.
(which will be used to change image visibility when `showImage()` method is called)

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".open-InputDataDialog", function () {
        var rowId = $(this).data('rowid');
        $("#rowid").val(rowId);
    });
    function showImage() {
        var rowId = $('#rowid').val();
        $('#myImg_'+rowId).show();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late reply @HastaDhana!
Your answer is giving me the idea, so i just add some codes in model to get the status showing. And in column status i create condition if status is 1 display the images but if status 0 not display. It works anyway..
cheers